# parity_codec::codec::Input is not implemented for Vec<u8> when decoding an extrinsic into a struct

Tags: rust, substrate

How would I decode the standard [Substrate extrinsic format](https://wiki.parity.io/Extrinsic) into a `Transaction` object in a way where it would be possible to get the `Sender`, preferably as a string?

I have started with this code with a hardcoded sample extrinsic data for testing in the `extrinsic_hex` variable:

```rust
use hex::decode;
use hex_literal::hex;
use parity_codec::{Decode, Encode, Input};
use primitives::generic::UncheckedMortalExtrinsic;
use std::fmt;
use std::fmt::Debug;

fn main() {
    let extrinsic_hex: &'static str =  "81ffd43593c715fdd31c61141abd04a99fd6822c8558854ccde39a5684e7a56da27d3c6b8941e2976034e67bdd1a999c3eff4403c8ceaf717f18d9760ab18573ab2ce870e9b751c2f14dd9883e54746e1eb6639978ceab49968c25176cc0d2507205040003000ca10f";
    let result = hex::decode(extrinsic_hex);
    match result {
        Ok(v1) => {
            let extr_option = UncheckedMortalExtrinsic::decode(&mut v1);
            ()
        }
        _ => {
            println!("Error decoding");
            ()
        }
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
error: duplicate lang item in crate `sr_io`: `panic_impl`.
  |
  = note: first defined in crate `std`.

error: duplicate lang item in crate `sr_io`: `oom`.
  |
  = note: first defined in crate `std`.

error[E0277]: the trait bound `std::vec::Vec<u8>: parity_codec::codec::Input` is not satisfied
  --> core/decaddr/src/main.rs:13:20
   |
13 |             let extr_option=UncheckedMortalExtrinsic::decode(&mut v1);
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `parity_codec::codec::Input` is not implemented for `std::vec::Vec<u8>`
   |
   = note: required by `parity_codec::codec::Decode::decode`
```

Let's pretend that the error `error: duplicate lang item in crate`sr_io`:`panic_impl`.` doesn't exist for now.

If I am understanding correctly, it doesn't work because `Vec` doesn't implement the [`parity_codec::Input` trait](https://crates.parity.io/parity_codec/trait.Input.html), am I right? If so, how would one add this trait to `Vec`? Or better said, what are the functions from the Substrate framework I am missing so the `Input` trait is automatically provided?

Comment: Please keep your error messages as plain as possible, if the duplicate lang item error is not a concern it is better if you remove it from the post, as i removed unnecessary warnings. And please provide your minimum toml to test this code.

Comment: According to github page of parity_codec Input is not implemented for Vec but it is [implemented for slice of byte array](https://github.com/paritytech/parity-codec/blob/06a6bdd736a5d710bb5d51c44e67e5e448e2f079/src/codec.rs#L114) so you can pass your slice of your vector as Input like this : `UncheckedMortalExtrinsic::decode(&v1[..])`

Comment: @ÖmerErden , I have solved the duplicated symbol error, it was due to using disabled default features in sr-primitives in Cargo.toml

Comment: Do not edit the question to [invalidate existing answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/290704/3956566).

Comment: @YvetteColomb , the question stays as before: `How to decode the extrinsic into a struct?`

Answer (score 0):

> If so, how would one add this trait to Vec ?

In your code, you can't. For coherence reasons, Rust says that an implementation of a trait X for a type Y must exist in the crate for X or the crate for Y.

> Or better said, what are the functions from Susbtrate framework I am missing so the Input trait is automatically provided?

If you [look at the "Implementors" part of the Input trait documentation](https://crates.parity.io/parity_codec/trait.Input.html#implementors) - you can see that every type that implements `std::io::Read` will implement `Input`.

As the comments say, the implementation that is useful for you is the one on `&[u8]`, which exists because it implements `std::io::Read`.

Comment: Thanks, but just passing the Input won't convert raw extrinsic to a struct, there will be other errors, after providing correct input to `UncheckedMortalExtrinsic::decode` function

Comment: I have updated the question, it is now showing the next error.

Comment: Don't update questions - you should instead ask a new question. Editing questions invalidates the answers you have already received, and stops others from getting help for the same problem as you had.